# How to use c-strings and avoid overflow c++

Tags: c++, c-strings

How do I use a c-string and avoid overflow? For example if I had the code:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int size = 1000;
    char * name = new char[size];
    getline(cin, name);
}
```

I don't know how long that persons name is going to be, so how do you avoid an overflow? If I allocated 1000 as a precaution, they could just as easily input 1001 characters. What can I do to stop this from happening?

edit: I have to be able to do this without the string class

Comment: Use `std::string` instead and make your life much simpler and your code easier to understand.

Comment: What do you think is the reason std::string was invented?

Comment: If you want to use a fixed buffer, use `cin.getline(name, size)`  documentation [here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istream/getline)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is a version of `std::getline()` which accepts `std::string` as target buffer. It is designed to take advantage of `std::string`'s auto-resize capability and prevent overflows. Example from [std::getline manpage](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/getline):

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    // greet the user
    std::string name;
    std::cout << "What is your name? ";
    std::getline(std::cin, name);
    std::cout << "Hello " << name << ", nice to meet you.\n";
}
```

In addition to the safety you asked about, `std::string` gives you also automatic memory management - so you don't need to remember to `delete` anything, which would be necessary in your example.

---

If you are not allowed to use `std::string`, you can use [`std::basic_istream::getline`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istream/getline), which comes in two forms:

```
basic_istream& getline( char_type* s, std::streamsize count );
basic_istream& getline( char_type* s, std::streamsize count, char_type delim );
```

It allows you to specify max number of characters to read and an optional delimiter. `std::basic_istream` is the base class for `std::istream`. A very popular instance of this class is [`std::cin`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/cin).

So basically, you can do:

```
char target[64];
std::cin.getline(target, 64);
```

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to add that I can't use strings

Comment: You don't need to include sstream but otherwise +1 this is the exact answer.

Comment: @Dante then you're not using C++, you're using C.

Comment: @Tas I don't know how to use c like malloc so I said c++.

Comment: @Dante I updated my answer to also respect non-std::string-based approach.

Comment: @MateuszGrzejek Thanks! I just noticed though that if you do go over the specified limit and you try to input a second time it doesn't work. What's going on here?